# Unique combinations of the elements of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What will be the mathematical notation for a set of playing cards obtained in such a way, so the cards from all ranks $R = \{Ace, 2, 3, ..., King\}$ are part of it and a card of a particular rank may have any, but only one of the four colors $C = \{Spades, Diamonds, Hearts, Clubs\}$. For example if the Jack is a Jack of Spades, then the Jack of Hearts, the Jack of Diamonds and the Jack of Clubs are not part of the set. However, the Queen may be a Queen of Diamonds in the same set. Again, no other Queens will be part of it. In other words, the value of the second element in the pair (C, R) should be unique for the set.

Comment: You may consider $C^R$, because it is sequence of items in $C$ of length $|R|$. And $R$ has an order.

Comment: This is a good solution too. Thank You for sharing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could denote it as the set $$S = \{(c, r) \in C \times R \}$$ such that $$\forall \ (c_1, r_1), (c_2, r_2) \in S, \\ r_1 = r_2 \implies c_1 = c_2$$

Comment: And what about if there was only one rank in the deck?

Comment: Then you're only allowed one card, correct? If I have a King of Spades for example, then I can't have any other color (Diamonds, ...). However, since there is only one rank, there is only one card

Comment: Great! But what about this notation: $S = \{(\mathtt{Spades} | \mathtt{Dimonds}| \mathtt{Hearts}| \mathtt{Clubs}, r) : r \in R\}$

Comment: I've never really seen that in standard literature to be honest.

Comment: But is it correct?

Comment: | means OR'ed values

Comment: or probably $S = \{(c, r) : c = (\mathtt{Spades} | \mathtt{Dimonds}| \mathtt{Hearts}| \mathtt{Clubs}), r \in R\}$

Comment: I suppose it could be - I'm not enough of an expert to answer :) Well, if it was computing, then people do use `|` as an `OR` combinator, but I'm not really sure about math

Comment: Yes, it is computing. That's why I used OR'ed values. Anyway, Your answer is what I need. Thank You for Your time!

Comment: you're welcome!